# "precompiler directive" "preprocessor directive"

Tags: c, directive

I was wondering if "precompile(r) directive" and "preprocessor directive" are the same thing? I am not familiar with the former, but just heard of it and found a little information about it on the internet with this [Google](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&safe=off&client=ubuntu&hs=j9u&channel=fs&q=%22precompile%20directive%22&aq=f&aqi=g-lv3g-jl1&aql=&oq=) search, such as p40 of "[C++ programming for the absolute beginner](http://books.google.com/books?id=ea2SOugw6g8C&pg=PT64&lpg=PT64&dq=%22precompile%20directive%22&source=bl&ots=PHcb2R1p3Z&sig=X_oUv15I2K-lk8mURgSgUVNa4AE&hl=en&ei=-_D4Te3LJYPMgQfk8OXwCw&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=6&ved=0CD8Q6AEwBQ#v=onepage&q=%22precompile%20directive%22&f=false)" by Dirk Henkemans and Mark Lee.

Comment: Where and how did you head of it? I don't think "precompiler" is a real word.

Comment: @Kerrek: For example, http://books.google.com/books?id=ea2SOugw6g8C&pg=PT64&lpg=PT64&dq=%22precompile+directive%22&source=bl&ots=PHcb2R1p3Z&sig=X_oUv15I2K-lk8mURgSgUVNa4AE&hl=en&ei=-_D4Te3LJYPMgQfk8OXwCw&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=6&ved=0CD8Q6AEwBQ#v=onepage&q=%22precompile%20directive%22&f=false

Comment: @Tim: Thank you. Unfortunately, that page alone throws many cringe-worthy moments at me... "tells the *compiler* to replace all occurrences": no, it's the *preprocessor*, the compiler never sees it. And you're not *declaring* a constant, you're just pasting a literal into your code. Oh well. I should recommend you consult a different book :-)

Comment: I think Stroustrup's original book is still a great book, it's both a very fine description of the language _and_ a reference. I'm sure others can come up with good recommendations, too, but is there anything in particular you're learning or working on at the moment?

Comment: I am learning the general ideas. I hope his book will not lose people with details but without big picture.

Answer (score 2):

Your question amounts to asking if people mean "[preprocessor](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=cpp) directive" when they say "precompile directive", and that's not an answerable question.

---

In a C or C++ context, I suspect people are very *likely* to be referring to preprocessor directives if they say "precompile directive".

The book you quote is one example of this.  It's talking about the C preprocessor directive "`#define`". I suspect it's using "precompile directive" as a description, not a name.

All of the search results you posted that I examined are posts by people seeking help with C preprocessor directives.

---

That said, I can't say for certain that's the case for *all* people at all times, though.

Microsoft possibly made a tool that uses "precompiler directives" according to the result of another search I made, but it wasn't talking about C, C++ or `cpp`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, they sound like the exactly the same thing. I think preprocessor directive is more commonly used (I've never heard of precompiler).

This is a pretty good list of directives / what they do:
http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/preprocessor/

Comment: If you have never heard of it, how can you assert that they are the same thing? Are apples and floobagotchies the same thing, too?

Comment: I have indeed never heard of it so I googled before answering the question, and lo-and-behold, the first result for precompiler directives is also the first result for preprocessor directives.

Comment: I can also [find stuff on the internet](http://www.makingstuffup.com/makingstuffup.php?view=single&item=8)... that's a minefield ;-)

Answer (score 1):

It depends a bit on context, but for most people most of the time, if you are working in pure C code, they are the same thing, though 'preprocessor directive' is far more common than 'precompile directive' or 'precompiler directive'.

Section **§6.10 Preprocessing Directives** of the ISO/IEC 9899:1999 standard indicates that 'preprocessor' or 'preprocessing' is more standard than 'precompile(r)'.

If, however, you work with ESQL/C (Embedded SQL in C), then there is a difference:

- The precompiler directives are aimed at the ESQL/C precompiler, which converts ESQL/C into pure C.
- The preprocessor directives are aimed at the C preprocessor, which is one part of the C compiler which (overall) converts C source code into object code or executables, etc.

The ESQL/C compiler I work with has directives such as:

```
$include sqlca;
$define APERITIF 32;
$include "header.h";
$ifdef APPETIZERS;
$define AVOCADO 1;
$endif;

#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    $ int var1;
    $ whenever error stop;
    $ database "whatever";
    $ select max(tabid) into :var1 from systables;
    printf("%d\n", var1);
    return 0;
}
```

The lines starting with a '$' are ESQL/C precompiler directives - aimed at the precompiler.  They give the ESQL/C precompiler the information needed to help it convert the embedded SQL statements into C code, which is then compiled by a full C compiler.  But the ESQL/C precompiler is also called the ESQL/C preprocessor (to distinguish it from the C preprocessor), so the distinction is not as hard and fast as all that.  In this case, the ESQL/C compiler as a whole is a shell script that runs the ESQL/C precompiler and then the C compiler.  (There are some extra complications in it that don't concern this question.)

Comment: "The preprocessor directives are aimed at the C preprocessor, which converts C into object code or executables, etc."?? The preprocessor doesn't usually do that. It usually processes preprocessor directives and removes comments to produce "pure" C source code. The _compiler_ compiles that into assembly, the _assembler_ turns that into binary objects, and the _linker_ links those into executables.